# imaginative complicated explanation in context

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Please explain in context:

1. the meaning of 'filibustered'
2. the meaning of 'Worlds'
3. What “unspoken question” is it about?

> It was a joke about futility, and at the same time a joke about will,
>   and subjectivity. If we **filibustered** the glasses into existence
>   between us did it matter that the paper-and-tape glasses didn't
>   persist? **Worlds** seemed to hang in the balance of that **unspoken
>   question**, and in a way they did. Our worlds. The glasses stood for our
>   own paper-thin new sensibilities, thrust against the bronze of the
>   adult world. Were we viable? Did we have to convince others, or was it
>   enough just to convince ourselves?

[Planet Big Zero](http://maxima-library.org/knigi/genre/b/309434?format=read)
by Jonathan Lethem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cited text uses English quite "creatively" - that business about "filibustering the glasses into existence", for example, certainly won't match any dictionary definitions!

But earlier paragraphs make it clear that the narrator and a school chum had been ***repeatedly*** putting crude "spectacles" (made of torn notebook paper and scotch tape) on a bronze bust of Toscanini in the main hall. Presumably the school janitor or a teacher repeatedly *removed* their handiwork, so the glasses didn't "persist" (they didn't "exist" in the sense of being real and permanent).

The highly metaphoric "filibustering" effectively means *causing something to happen / become real by continuously / repeatedly talking about it / bringing attention to it*. Usually, filibustering is about causing something (a parliamentary ***vote***) to ***not*** become real (by continuously talking), but here Lethem is extending the meaning to ***make*** something become real through extended talking, rather than ***prevent*** something happening.

---

"Worlds hanging in the balance" is another highly metaphorical usage that nets down to ***important things were going on***, and I'd guess the "unspoken question" was something along the lines of ***Do those "glasses" really "exist"?*** (they certainly persist in the *minds* of the boys, even if in the real world they're just bits of paper that flicker briefly into existence every day before being removed).

---

That's my take, anyway. But it's all very "literary / poetic / figurative", so you're at liberty to interpret things differently if you like.